# Problem with type constrained protocols defined in a separate module

Tags: ios, swift, module, protocols

I'm running into an issue where type constrained protocols defined in a separate module aren't acknowledging the constrained type.

For example if I define the following protocol:

```
public protocol SomeVCProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func something()
}
```

And conform to it:

```
extension SomeViewController: SomeVCProtocol {
    func something() { }
}

let someVC: SomeVCProtocol = SomeViewController()
someVC.something()
someVC.present(UIViewController(), animated: true)
```

There's no issue here. I can call the protocol-specific methods *and* `UIViewController` methods. However the moment I define `SomeVCProtocol` in a separate module, I no longer have access to the `UIViewController` methods. Is this just a shortcoming of Swift, or am I just missing something?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding your architecture, and what's being accessed from where, correctly ... but if you mean you're trying to access the VC's methods from a different module, are those methods marked public?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to access the VC's methods from a separate module. The methods themselves are just the UIKit UIViewController methods which are all declared as `open`. The type-constrained protocol itself is defined within a framework, and imported/used within my main app (a separate module).

Comment: OK, with you now.  Still non the wiser though I'm afraid - I can't see why there should be a problem!